# Random character showing up on my WordPress site and I don't know where it is coming from

Tags: html, wordpress

I built a WordPress site https://columbusguitarrepair.com on a test server, then moved it to a live server. Now, it has a strange "b" character in the top left of the site. I have no idea where it is coming from, and am unable to find how to get rid of it. Any ideas?

I looked in all the widgets, uninstalled and reinstalled the widgets and cannot figure it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you check the source code for the page, you'll see the "b" is inserted before even the DOCTYPE declaration. I would recommend you check the header.php and index.php files to see if something there is causing it. Something else that might be causing it is WordPress's smiley via JetPack. You can try disabling that to see if it helps.

Comment: Check the first line of your theme's PHP file for `b` just before the opening php tag `<?php`. Most probably `header.php', `index.php` or `functions.php`

Comment: Thanks for your responses - I've checked all the above-mentioned files and cannot find the "b" anywhere. I am also getting some additional errors, when I tried to install another plugin and it gave me the error
Installation failed: b{"success":true,"data":{"install":"plugin","slug":"health-check","pluginName":"Health Check &amp; Troubleshooting","activateUrl":"https:\/\/columbusguitarrepair.com\/wp-admin\/plugins.php?_wpnonce=ebc0d6cd07&action=activate&plugin=health-check\/health-check.php"}}

Comment: So there is obviously something that is really wrong with my site - I noticed the "b" is at the start of the error message, so could it be in my database or something?

Comment: What you can do is put some hints in your php files. For example, on various lines in your index.php put `echo "1";` then further down `echo "2";` etc. Then keep narrowing it down that way. By doing this you will be able to tell where exactly that `b` character is coming from.

Comment: Also, why is that if I go to `https://columbusguitarrepair.com/blah` I still get your site? It should be giving me a 404 not found or something similar.

Comment: @kojow7 Hi - thank you for the suggestion - I will try to narrow it down. I have no idea why the site would show up if you use that url - I tried it also - very strange. I reinstalled Wordpress, reinstalled the themes, disable and reenabled all the plugin, and checked the database and can find no "b". Also, I am using the Genesis Framework with a child theme, so I can't even find the "Doctype" and other stuff that is at the top of the page when I open in Google Dev console. Thanks again for your help - this is VERY frustrating.

Comment: You should be able to do a recursive grep search for DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

Go to theme from admin dashboard and check active theme. Then go to the theme folder and activated theme header.php file. And check header.php there you have a b letter before

Hope it will be removed.

Comment: Thank you - but I have checked all the files and there is no "b" anywhere in header.php, index.php, functions.php, wp-config.php, or any other file that I can find. The site is not allowing plugin installation/updates, theme installations, etc, so the problem is somewhere deeper - I think I need to just reinstall and be done with it. Thanks